# Random number generation not working like it should in Pascal

Tags: random, numbers, pascal

I am trying to make a battle system where the player has to guess a random number each time and hope he will win. The problem is that the random number is generated only ONCE. Why?

```
unit game;
interface
uses a,b,reason,crt;
implementation
var health,ehealth: integer;
var a2:String;
var rand3,guess:Integer;
begin
  ClrScr;
  ehealth:=5;
  health:=10;
  Repeat
    Randomize;
    rand3:=Random (1);
    writeln('YOUR HP:',health);
    writeln('ENEMY HP:',ehealth);
    write('Guess the number (1 or 2):');
    Readln(guess);
    if (rand3+1) = guess then
    ehealth:=ehealth-1
    else
    health:=health-1;
    ClrScr;
  until (ehealth = 0) or (health = 0);
  writeln('GAME OVER!');
  readln;
    end;
```

Comment: That's not how it works. You need to call `Randomize` just *once* (before your loop), then call `Random` for the numbers (inside your loop). The documentation explains this explicitly.

Comment: @lurker I've removed Randomize from the repeat loop and placed it after begin, but the problem still persists.

Comment: If you're looking for a real number between 0 and 1, you need to call `Random` with no arguments. The documentation describes that, too. If you pass an integer, you get a random number between 0 and something strictly less than the number you passed.

Comment: Didn't know of that, thank you!

Comment: It's described [here in the documentation](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/random.html). :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i remember, the random function in pascal return a number between 0 and (N-1). So if you want a random number 0 or 1 you need to call Random(2). Also move Randomize just after the begin.